# Black rectangle on CyanogenMod (AOSP) browser with Quick Controls enabled

Tags: cyanogenmod, browser

I have fallen in love with a browser built in CyanogenMod 12.1, but there is a problem with a black rectangle which has shown about 3 days ago and it do not disappear after rebooting the device

I discovered that the black bar is visible when I enabled Quick Controls, but I do not want to disable it, because it is a major advantage of this browser.

My device is Motorola Moto G 2nd gen (x1072).

Screenshot

[image: black rectangle on AOSP browser]

Comment: try clearing the cache and other app data.

Comment: no change, I discovered that the square is visible when I use quick search applet, but i do not want to disable it, because it is a major advantage of this browser

Comment: Here you are. Um sorry rectangle.

Comment: Seems a known issue on [AOSP Issue Tracker #39811](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39811). Try some of the suggestions on recent posts, and let us know the result.

Comment: Also, I included your comment to the question, but replaced it with "Quick Controls" since I didn't find any result with "Quick Search applet". If this is a mistake, feel free to edit back.

Comment: I can't find any solution there.;((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has known. You must disable all accessibility service in accessibility setting. But this is bad because the developer didn't fix this bug till now